# regexp for find number in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string fromat:

```
session=11;reserID=1000001
```

How to get string array of number?

My code:

```
 var value = "session=11;reserID=1000001";
 var numbers =  Regex.Split(value, @"^\d+");
```

Comment: If you want to find occurrences of something, then search for something (`Regex.Matches()`), instead of splitting on "not something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably were on the right track but forgot the character class:

```
Regex.Split(value, @"[^\d]+");
```

You can also write it shorter by using `\D+` which is equivalent.

However, you'd get an empty element at the start of the returned array, so caution when consuming the result. Sadly, Regex.Split() doesn't have an option that removes empty elements (`String.Split` does, however). A not very pretty way of resolving that:

```
Regex.Replace(value, @"[^\d;]", "").Split(';');
```

based on the assumption that the semicolon is actually the relevant piece where you want to split.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> 'session=11;reserID=1000001' -replace '[^\d;]+' -split ';'
11
1000001
```

Another option would be to just skip the element:

```
Regex.Split(...).Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: :Thanks. But your code returns 3 items. The first is just empty string.

Comment: Of course, the regex splits at `session=` too, which is a run of non-digits.

Comment: :How to not return empty element?

Comment: It's not the most logical and certainly not the most efficient way to do this. I personally prefer @spenders approach a lot over this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex
 .Matches("session=11;reserID=1000001", @"\d+") //match all digit groupings
 .Cast<Match>() //promote IEnumerable to IEnumerable<Match> so we can use Linq
 .Select(m => m.Value) //for each Match, select its (string) Value
 .ToArray() //convert to array, as per question
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net has built in feature without using RegEx.Try `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`, passing the string. You would need to reference the `System.Web` assembly, but it shouldn't require a web context.

```
  var value = "session=11;reserID=1000001";
  NameValueCollection numbers = 
      System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(value.Replace(";","&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers =  Regex.Split(value, @".*?(.\d+).*?");
```

or
to return each digit:

```
var numbers =  Regex.Split(value, @".*?(\d).*?");
```

Answer (score 0):

I will re-use my code from another question:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sauce = htm.Text; //htm = textbox
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (Match iMatch in myRegex.Matches(sauce))
        {
            txt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + iMatch.Value);//txt= textbox
        }

    }
```

If you want to play around with regex here is a good site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
They also have a desktop app: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/ - It uses adobe air so install that first.